# How can I use glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, ...) on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, opengl

I am trying to use `GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D` in my code, but it won't compile under Mac OS X (10.6). I included `gl.h` and `glext.h`, but for this code:

```
int prevTextureBinding;
glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING, &prevTextureBinding);
```

I always get this error:

```
../FramebufferGroup.cpp:365: error:
    'GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING' was not declared in this scope
```

When using other OpenGL enums (like `GL_TEXTURE_2D`) I don't have any problems and can compile just fine - so my question is:

- **Does anybody know if
  GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING is supported
  under Mac OS X**

... I tried using `GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING_EXT` as well, but the apple documentation seems to suggest that `GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING` should actually be a valid parameter:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glGet.3.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called `GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D`, not `GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING`

Comment: ok - thank you - it seems like I actually got confused over 'GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING_EXT' and 'GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D' and didn't notice that they actually changed the location of the '_2D' part - thanks!